# change data-content with navbar

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-mobile

I've got a navbar and i just want to change what is below that. I'm using Jquery mobile.
I've found this but it doesn't do it properly.

```
<body id="stage" class="theme">
<div data-role="page" id="page1">
    <div data-role="header">
        <h1>Welcome to the Hunt</h1>
    </div>
        <div data-role="navbar">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#page1" class="ui-btn-active ui-state-persist">Mes parties</a></li>
                <li><a href="#page2">Parties en cours</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div data-role="page" id="page2">
    <div data-role="header">
        <h1>Welcome to the Hunt</h1>
    </div>
        <div data-role="navbar">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#page1" class="ui-btn-active ui-state-persist">Mes parties</a></li>
                <li><a href="#page2">Parties en cours</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you don't have any data on any of those pages. just a navbar...
you should add a content div to each page:

```
<div data-role="content">
   <p>Welcom to page 1</p>  
</div><!-- /content -->
```

(make sure that on page 2 the content div will say something different.)

Second, you don't change the active item (page) in the navbar.
the "class" part on the menu should be part of the current page only.

Third, I think you have unmatched `</DIV>` in your code

--
EDIT:

To avoid refreshing the menu - you can put the navbar in the specific page header, give the header ID and make sure the id will be the same for both page headers:

```
<div data-id="PersistentNav" data-position="fixed" data-role="header">
```

Do it for both pages...

Same ID will force jquery not to refresh the menu

and now, with the code:

```
<body id="stage" class="theme">

<div data-role="page" id="page1">
    <div data-id="PersistentNav" data-position="fixed" data-role="header">
        <h1>Welcome to the Hunt</h1>
        <div data-role="navbar">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#page1" class="ui-btn-active ui-state-persist">Mes parties</a></li>
                <li><a href="#page2">Parties en cours</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div data-role="content">   
             <p>Welcom to page 1</p>    
    </div><!-- /content -->
</div>


<div data-role="page" id="page2">
    <div data-id="PersistentNav" data-position="fixed" data-role="header">
        <h1>Welcome to the Hunt</h1>
        <div data-role="navbar">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#page1" >Mes parties</a></li>
                <li><a href="#page2" class="ui-btn-active ui-state-persist">Parties en cours</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>

    </div>
    <div data-role="content">   
             <p>Welcom to page 2</p>    
     </div><!-- /content -->
</div>

</body>
```

Comment: Okay, and do you know how to do it without refreshing ?

Answer (score 0):

```
<div style="margin:0 auto;">
<div data-role="page" style="width:400px" id="page1">


<div data-role="header">
    <h1>Welcome to the Hunt</h1>
</div>
<div data-role="navbar">
    <ul>
    <li><a href="#page1" class="ui-btn-activeui-statepersist">Mesparties</a></li>
        <li><a href="#page2">Parties en cours</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div data-role="content">
    from 1st page
</div>

</div>


<div data-role="page" id="page2" style="width:400px">
<div data-role="header">
    <h1>Welcome to the Hunt</h1>
</div>
<div data-role="navbar">
<ul>
<li><a href="#page1" >Mes parties</a></li>
  <li><a href="#page2" class="ui-btn-active ui-state-persist">Partiesecours</a>    </li>
</ul>
</div>
    <div data-role="content">
    from 2nd page
    </div>
 </div>
 </div>
```

Above code will change the content based on navbar.